# Presentation of blog entries with small word count?

Tags: usability, gui-design, blog

How would you present a list of blog entries with small word count from 50 to 100 words? So that you have a list of clickable links of titles that takes you to that blog entry with small word count?

Comment: How are you displaying it at the moment? What is wrong with the way you are doing it? It's hard to provide you with a solution if you've not really stated what the problem that you currently have is.

Comment: If all the entries are 50-100 words, I don't think I'd _want_ clickable links to take me to each one, I'd probably prefer to just read them "in-page" in a stream, rather like the comments on Stack Exchange sites.  If some of the entries go above a certain threshold (e.g. 120 words), then you could show the first 100 words with a "_Read more_" style link (that either expanded in-page or displayed the full entry in another page).  (_For context, you question is about 40 words; this comment about 90 words_).

Answer (score 0):

Like @JonW mentioned, I can't say whether your current approach is in fact incorrect. But if you're starting from scratch then take the Stack Exchange approach.

- Make headers/title mandatory for each blog post and have a word limit for it
- If not, select a word limit that fits the list view of the blog. Use [ellipses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis) to block out the overflowing elements

[image: SE question list]